# I am not able see generated QR Code Image in Xamarin using ZXing.NET.Mobile

Tags: c#, xamarin, zxing

Please help me ,

I am not able see generated QR Code Image. What am I doing wrong !

I have used Xamarin Forms . I have Simply used a Image to be populated in StackLayout

```
public class BarcodePage : ContentPage
{
    public BarcodePage ()
    {
        Image img = new Image {
            Aspect = Xamarin.Forms.Aspect.AspectFit
        };


        img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream (() => {
            var writer = new BarcodeWriter {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,

                Options = new EncodingOptions {
                    Height = 200,
                    Width = 600
                }
            };
            var bitmap = writer.Write ("My Content");

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
            bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
            return ms;
        });

        var Layout = new StackLayout {
            Children = 
            { img}
        };

        Content = Layout;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are writing the Bitmap data to the `MemoryStream` using the `Compress()` method the position of the stream will be at the end when you return it.

Make sure to reset the stream's position before returning it by adding this line.

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

The `Image` will now read the stream from the beginning, rather than from the end.